# Obj C MD5 differs from PHP md5() function

Tags: php, objective-c, xml, md5

I'm current having some trouble with this code Snippet:

```
- (NSString *) md5:( NSString *) str 
{
    const char *cStr = [str UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), result ); // This is the md5 call
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:
            @"%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x",
            result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], 
            result[4], result[5], result[6], result[7],
            result[8], result[9], result[10], result[11],
            result[12], result[13], result[14], result[15]
            ];  
}
```

This method is generating a hash of a downloaded XML File, which is complete different from the PHP function md5().

So how do I get the Hash which is identically to PHPs one or vice versa.

Comment: There is another MD5 implementation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104362/187954

Comment: To get the identical hash, supply the identical source data. Log the exact bytes of the *input*, not the output, for both Objective-C and PHP. Start with a small file to test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If You do `echo md5('hello')` in PHP You would receive a 32 char long string, but when You use Your code snippet in ObjC, You transform the string chars to the HEX format (by using the formater %02x) - see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265 and here: [Unsigned Char Array to Hex Representation NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977650/unsigned-char-array-to-hex-representation-nsstring).

And You use only half the MD5 string chars to create this HEX formated string... Either return the `result` immediately or do the same HEX transformation in PHP :-)

Answer (score 0):

The function found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104362) does the job perfectly in my testing:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

...
+ (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input {
    const char* str = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

    NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
    for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
    }
    return ret;
}
...
```

Matched up with PHP's implementation exactly. It originally comes from the Facebook Connect source code.